# SonarRunner fails because of missing FxCop

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, sonarqube, fxcop

My TFS 2013 build fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".
```

I do not have or want the FxCop assembly. FxCop is not compatible with .NET 4.5 anymore. I use SonarQube 5.1.1 and SonarRunner 2.4. I have plugins for C++ and C#.
How can I run SonarRunner without FxCop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the FxCop rules from your profile (you can locate them by doing a Repository=FxCop search within the profile). Then FxCop won't be invoked and your analysis will work.

Answer (score 1):

FxCop is actually compatible with Framework 4.5 and up, but you need to grab the Code Analysis location that comes with Visual Studio.

The default location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop
```

So the simplest way to get it working is to install a compatible version of Visual Studio on your build server, an Express edition of 2013 should do. Or you can copy your own `Static Analysis Tools\FxCop` folder over to your build server.

To disable the FxCop rules in Sonar, I believe you can set:

```
sonar.fxcop.mode=disabled
```

And in the C# quality profile section of Sonar ensure that all FxCop related rules are disabled.

Comment: [It looks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17634211/21567) though, you need to install the Visual Studio Express _Desktop_ Edition.

Comment: I did not know that. I saw this [website](http://michaelsync.net/category/fxcopcode-analysis) and thought it was put on ice for a while. I will try installing VS Express Desktop.

Comment: Just install a version of VS for which you're already licensed. There are no license requirements for Visual Studio on a build server.

Comment: @Daniel as far as I know that is for Visual Studio licensed under MSDN. Not retail licenses.

Comment: I tried installing VS on the build agent. The result was that error message changed, but the build still did not go through with another error message related to FxCop. This is why I ended up following G. Ann's advice. Now the build is happy again.